# Read crash in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can we save crash details in a database (core data) on the iPhone? For instance, after reading from console.or device crash logs?

I want to be able to read crash details through code, and want to save it in a database.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look a [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). It can capture Exceptions when they are thrown, format a crash report and save it to disk.

If you are trying to gather crash reports from your apps in your users hands take a look at [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net). It uses PLCrashReporter inside.

Comment: To extend the answer, there is an open source framework QuincyKit.net that works on top of PLCrashReporter, which is also used with the HockeyApp service. The framework has a backend based on PHP and MySQL to collect and kinda group similar crash reports. HockeyApp does the same and adds server side symbolication and grouping by class, method, line numbers etc.